# Doing math on dates ruby (json parsed date string) Syntax error

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have parsed a date in json like below

```
DateTime.parse(parsed["LastTimeReportGenerated"])
```

Now I'm trying to do `Time.now-DateTime.parse(parsed["LastTimeReportGenerated"])`

Whitout success. Getting the error message

```
scheduler caught exception:
can't convert DateTime into an exact number
```

What is the correct syntax? Sorry for this simple question but could't find an obvious answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-`-Method of the `Time` object only accepts another `Time` object or a number (seconds) to subtract. You are giving a `DateTime` object, which can be converted to a `Time` object:

```
Time.now-DateTime.parse(parsed["LastTimeReportGenerated"]).to_time
```

Comment: You can just do `Time.parse`